# i cant install pyaudio, a weird error is showing up?

Tags: python, linux

i used command pip3 install pyaudio,this error shows up

btw, im using ubuntu 20.04

i was using speech recogniser module in python but this error shows up

and im using visual studio code

any thoughts?

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2f7g2sg2/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2f7g2sg2/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-ut55o31r
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-2f7g2sg2/pyaudio/
  Complete output (16 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_portaudiomodule.o
  src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
     29 | #include "portaudio.h"
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2f7g2sg2/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2f7g2sg2/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-lr0qj7xe/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/vedarsh/.local/include/python3.8/pyaudio
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-2f7g2sg2/pyaudio/
    Complete output (16 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
       29 | #include "portaudio.h"
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2f7g2sg2/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2f7g2sg2/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-lr0qj7xe/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/vedarsh/.local/include/python3.8/pyaudio Check the logs for full command output.
```

any answers?

Comment: You did not install the required portaudio library headers. Try `sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few more dependencies which have to be manually installed before using python's pyaudio. 
Execute these commands and you must be fine:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0

sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libav-tools

sudo pip install pyaudio
```

You might also refer to this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/diegopacheco/d5d4507988eff995da297344751b095e).

Answer (score 4):

Run this command and your problem will be fixed

`pip install pyaudio` -> error

`sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev` -> success

`pip install pyaudio` -> success

Answer (score 0):

for centos:

```
sudo yum install portaudio portaudio-devel
```